# Why is this Excel import to my database leaving rows empty while they contain data?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Currently working with Excel and Laravel to import a sheet to my database. The uploading and showing works (yay!) However, I noticed it seems to leave out some columns. The next to last two. The last one gets filled and the one before that does too, so I am curious as to why this does not work as it should.

Database rows:

[image]

Table structure:
[image]

Excel sheet I am importing (there are more rows but I am limiting it to the troublesome area):
[image]

Data import class (this is where I assign the values to the variables):
[image]

importeren.blade.php (this is where the importing happens). Reading out the data for each entry using a foreach loop.
[image]

As you can see, they are all numeric values, and all of them load fine except for "ADVJaarwerk" and "PeriodiekeADV"

Sidenote: I put char64 because my laravel application demanded me to do so. The tables all run fine except for the specified two. I am honestly wondering why.

Comment: Maybe this is a mass assignment issue, does your model have `ADVJaarwerk` and `PeriodiekeADV` listed in the `$fillable` property?

Comment: Please comment this again but as an answer so I can mark it as the solution. This was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `ADVJaarwerk` and `PeriodiekeADV` attributes are mass assignable in your model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    ...
    'ADVJaarwerk',
    'PeriodiekeADV',
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

it because of your $row['ADVJaarwerk'] or $row['PeriodiekeADV'] write wrong naming conversion is wrong

change to excel file field name adj jaarwerk and variable name $row['adj_jaarwerk'];

change to excel file field name periodiekeadv and variable name $row['periodiekeadv'];

and check fillable [] property in model..

i hope so it works